# How to query a many to many relation with a condition in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I guess this is a really simple question, but I am not able to find out any solution! Neither google it.

I am working with Spring Boot JPA repositories, and I have a many to many relation between two tables. Table A --> User, table B --> Role.

The data is already recorded in the database, but how can I get for example all the roles that a specific user has?

I have successfully executed the simple queries. Get all users, get all roles, get user by id, etc. But I cannot get this one.

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much!!

```
package com.mb.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;

    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean tokenExpired;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_userId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public boolean isTokenExpired() {
        return tokenExpired;
    }
    public void setTokenExpired(boolean tokenExpired) {
        this.tokenExpired = tokenExpired;
    }
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

```
package com.mb.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;


@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int roleId;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;





    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }






}
```

```
package com.mb.repo;



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mb.model.Role;
import com.mb.model.User;


public interface IUserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

```
package com.mb.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mb.model.Role;


public interface IRoleRepo extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>{



}
```

```
    @Autowired
    private IUserRepo repo;

User loggedUser = repo.findByEmail(username);
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of code what you have tried so far?. So it's easy for us to give a solution.

Comment: I have attached the code of the 2 entities, the 2 repos and an example of how I get a user by email. If you need any piece of additional code just tell me! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello @mikizas, expected op is to retrieve all roles for user with some id?

Comment: Hello @PatelRomil, yeap. The result should be a list of roles for a specific user. I am still understanding how JPA works. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I am using MySQL.

Comment: Are there any constraints on from which repository implementation you are pulling from? You can link the tables either way but as you had roles already joined with user table you can simple get the user by id and the the user object returned will have all the roles attached to it